# Regex to compare strings with Umlaut and non-Umlaut variations

Tags: javascript, regex

Can anyone help me with a javascript regular expression that I can use to compare strings that are the same, taking into acccount their non-Umlaut-ed versions.

for example, in German the word `Grüße` can also be written `Gruesse`. These two strings are to be considered identical. The mappings (ignoring casings for the moment) are:

- ä = ae
- ü = ue
- ö = oe
- ß = ss

As there are not many "couplets" to consider I could do a replace for each variation, but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way, especially as this use case might need to be extended in future to include e.g. Scandanavian characters...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

something like

```
tr = {"ä":"ae", "ü":"ue", "ö":"oe", "ß":"ss" }

replaceUmlauts = function(s) {
    return s.replace(/[äöüß]/g, function($0) { return tr[$0] })
}

compare = function(a, b) {
    return replaceUmlauts(a) == replaceUmlauts(b)
}

alert(compare("grüße", "gruesse"))
```

you can easily extends this by adding more entries to "tr"

not quite elegant, but works

Comment: that looks very handy - I'll give that a try. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Regular expressions aren't *quite* powerful enough to do this properly, though you could hack it  into almost working with them.

What you want is called **Unicode Normalization.**  A Normalized string is one converted to a common form so you can compare them. You tagged your post "javascript", however, Javascript doesn't have a built in standard library to do this, and I am not aware of one offhand.
Most server-side languages do have one, though. For example, the [Normalizer Class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.normalizer.php) in PHP. Python and Perl have equivalents, as do Microsoft stuff, I'm sure.

Check out the wikipedia article on [Unicode Equivalence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence) for more information.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to [stereofrogs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909815/regex-to-compare-strings-with-umlaut-and-non-umlaut-variations/1910057#1910057):

```
tr = {"\u00e4":"ae", "\u00fc":"ue", "\u00f6":"oe", "\u00df":"ss" }

ersetzeUmlauts = function(s) {
    return s.replace(/[\u00e4|\u00fc|\u00f6|\u00df]/g, function($0) { return tr[$0] })
}
```

I was dealing with Umlauts in an Aptana/Eclipse script and the normal characters ('ä' etc.) didn't do the trick for me.

Comment: Thank you so much for listing those \codes  ... i was going nuts as to why Javascript wouldn't replace standard "ß" ... just didn't recognize it.

Answer (score 5):

**I have another way :** ( purpose : sorting arrays )

```
function umlaut(str) {
 return str
  .replace(/Â|À|Å|Ã/g, "A")
  .replace(/â|à|å|ã/g, "a")
  .replace(/Ä/g, "AE")
  .replace(/ä/g, "ae")
  .replace(/Ç/g, "C")
  .replace(/ç/g, "c")
  .replace(/É|Ê|È|Ë/g, "E")
  .replace(/é|ê|è|ë/g, "e")
  .replace(/Ó|Ô|Ò|Õ|Ø/g, "O")
  .replace(/ó|ô|ò|õ/g, "o")
  .replace(/Ö/g, "OE")
  .replace(/ö/g, "oe")
  .replace(/Š/g, "S")
  .replace(/š/g, "s")
  .replace(/ß/g, "ss")
  .replace(/Ú|Û|Ù/g, "U")
  .replace(/ú|û|ù/g, "u")
  .replace(/Ü/g, "UE")
  .replace(/ü/g, "ue")
  .replace(/Ý|Ÿ/g, "Y")
  .replace(/ý|ÿ/g, "y")
  .replace(/Ž/g, "Z")
  .replace(/ž/, "z"); 
}
```

Comment: also đćč etc for croatian

Answer (score 1):

`Regex` isn't better technology to solve this problem.

You should consider to create a dictionary to store your Umlaut character as key and non-Umlaut as value; Then you can to iterate over yourdictionary, check if it exists on your string and take appropriate action.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pipe as an or in a group for each matching like this `(ä|ae)`.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to process your regexp 'input' so that it replaces for example 'ä' with (ae|ä)' - not hardcode the mappings to your regexps. I am completely ignorant to javascript (ok, i know document.write() but that's about it) - but here is the same in  pseudo code;

instead of doing

```
regexp_match("Grüße|Gruesse",somestring)
```

You should do something like:

```
mappings = (("ä","ae"),("ö","oe"),("ü","ue"))
def my_regexp_match(regexp,input) {
    for key,value in mappings {
         new_regexp = regexp.replace(key,"("+key+"|"+value+")")
    }
    regexp_match(new_regexp,input)
}
my_regexp_match("Grüße",somestring)
```

Sorry for being so "pythonic" - I do not know if you have re.compile() -like structure in javascript, but if you do - you should do the for -loop when compiling the matcher, not in my_regexp_match()

Comment: Braces are pythonic? :P  At least use non-capturing groups, but this still fails for character classes (`[äö]`).