# Manipulate input string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to attach a form input to a url parameter upon submit:

```
$(function() {
   $('#indexSearchBtn').click( function() {
        window.location = $(this).attr('href') + $('#indexSearch').val();
        return false;
    });
```

So far so good. But I'd like to replace german umlauts and spaces:
`ä,ö,ü` to `ae,oe,ue` and spaces to `-`

Is this possible or does this need some regex wizardry?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909815/regex-to-compare-strings-with-umlaut-and-non-umlaut-variations Refer